# Computing statistics over a stream for a given window

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a ticker KStream that that ticks frequently (think seconds), and I want to compute various statistics over a 24 hour window. For example, 24 hour change, the difference in price between a given point and one 24 hours before it.

My output for my desired input is:

```
t1 -> t1c1
t2 -> t1c2
t3 -> t1c3
```

Where `t1` is the input ticker, and `t1c1` is the input ticker with additional statistics computed for the 24 hour window preceding it.

I've considered a few ways of doing this that haven't worked:
* Window my ticker stream by size 24 hours with 1 second hops.

```
builder.stream(rawPriceTickerTopic, ...)
            .groupByKey()
            .windowedBy(
                    TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1))
                    .advanceBy(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1))
            .reduce((value1, value2) ->
                    value1.tickerWithStatsFrom(value2), ...)                
            .toStream();
```

However, this generates an immense number of output points, as each input ticker generates an output ticker for each window it is a member of.

- Keep some kind of time series store up to date, get the the value 24 hours previous from the store, and compute my statistics ticker from that, however this seems to be going against the point of streams.

Comment: `However, this generates an immense number of output points, as each input ticker generates an output ticker for each window it is a member of.` Obviously -- you are using TimeWindows. If you indent to use a "sliding window" and only maintain a single 'current/newest' window, this is not supported out-of-the-box as it does not allow to handle late arriving records. Your approach using a non-windowed aggregation to mimic a sliding window seems to be a good way -- however, it does not take out-of-order records into account.

Comment: In my solution below, if an out of order record is sent to a stream, it will hit my aggregator out of order, and be sorted by its timestamp. This would mean that records following on include it in their aggregation, but not the records previously to it, that should have. I haven't been able to understand how Kafka handles out of order records when windowing - does the stream processor recompute the aggregation and generate another output record?

Comment: Kafka Streams maintains all windows in parallel (until they expire) and recomputes the result if a late record arrives. Thus, it also updates "old" windows, something you don't do -- you only update the latest window (as you only maintain a single window) and drop records that are older than the window end-time. Kafka Streams maintains window independently of the window size for a configured retention period (default 1 day). Thus, if your window size is only 1 hour, a record can arrive many hours later and will still be included in the result.

Comment: I've read with [buffering](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-63%3A+Unify+store+and+downstream+caching+in+streams) you make a trade off between CPU and low latency, but since I want the price tickers with low latency, I'm not sure that's a trade off I can make as I need low latency prices. I still have the raw ticker topic should I need to calculate accurate statistics over historic data. Thanks for the help - it has been a journey learning about Kafka! It is an amazing tool.

Comment: That a tradeoff you need to decide on -- latency vs output rate vs handling-late-data. TimeWindows allow to handle late data and you can tradeoff latency vs. output rate via the cache size. Or you use your custom solution (that is not bad at all!) and get low latency and low output rate but cannot handle late data. Note, that your custom solution implements a sliding-window while a time-window implements a hopping window -- those provide slightly different semantics and handling late records for sliding windows is tricky (that's why we don't have them yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My final solution here was to abandon windowing and simply aggregate over my tickers, maintaining my own 24 hour window in the aggregator. This still doesn't feel like the best way and there's a nagging feeling that I could have solved it with Kafka's built in windowing concepts.

As said above, I use simple aggregation with my aggregator:

```
streamBuilder.stream(tickerTopic, Consumed.with(...)
                .groupByKey()
                .aggregate(MyAggregator::new,
                        (key, value, aggregate) -> aggregate.addTicker(value),
                        Materialized.with(...)
                .toStream()
```

The result is that for every record in the original ticker stream, I get an aggregated value in my output stream. My aggregators logic is simple:

- Add a new ticker to the ordered collection.
- Discard any tickers that are more than 24 hours older that this new latest ticker.
- Compute the new 24 hour change.

(This technique could be used for any kind of calculation over a given window, for example a moving average.)

Sample code for the aggregator:

```
public class MyAggregator {

    private BigDecimal change;

    private TreeSet<Ticker> orderedTickers = new TreeSet<>(MyAggregator::tickerTimeComparator);

    public MyAggregator () {
        this.windowMilis = 86400000;
    }

    public MyAggregator addTicker(Ticker ticker) {
        orderedTickers.add(ticker);
        cleanOldTickers();
        change = getLatest().getAsk().subtract(getEarliest().getAsk());
        return this;
    }

    public BigDecimal getChange() {
        return change;
    }

    public Ticker getEarliest() {
        return orderedTickers.first();
    }

    public Ticker getLatest() {
        return orderedTickers.last();
    }

    private void cleanOldTickers() {
        Date endOfWindow = latestWindow();

        Iterator<Ticker> iterator = orderedTickers.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Ticker next = iterator.next();
            if (next.getTimestamp().before(endOfWindow)) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
            // The collection is sorted by time so if we get here we can break.
            break;
        }
    }

    private Date latestWindow() {
        return new Date(getLatest().getTimestamp().getTime() - windowMilis);
    }

    private static int tickerTimeComparator(Ticker t1, Ticker t2) {
        return t1.getTimestamp().compareTo(t2.getTimestamp());
    }

}
```